# FreeRTOS task is taking more than the previous one, what will happen with the previous and current one?

Tags: freertos

Suppose that we have **Task 1** and **Task 2** started on the **same core**.

**Task 1** is the first to be run by the Scheduler and calls the `vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS)`.

Scheduler then sees that **Task 1** is now in blocked state and runs **Task 2**, but **Task 2** is taking **200 ms** to execute. What will happen with **Task 1**:

- Will the Scheduler Block **Task 2** after **100 ms** to return back to **Task 1**
- Will the Scheduler continue executing **Task 2** and after that back to **Task 1**, which means that the delay will not be **100 ms** for **Task 1**

I have tried somehow to block **Task 2** for more that the **Task 1**'s delay, but I can't.

**EDIT:**

**Test - Task 1 has highest priority than Task 2:**

**Task 1** will be executed first,because it has higher priority than **Task 2**.

During the execution **Task 1** will be delayed for **100 ms** and put to blocked state.

The Scheduler behind checks at interval all tasks and will see that **Task 1** is **blocked** and **Task 2** is ready and will execute it.

While the **Task 2** is executed **100 ms** have passed and the Scheduler behind will see that **Task 1** is at ready state and will execute it, because it has higher priority than **Task 1**. Due to that **Task 2** will be blocked.

After the execution of **Task 1** the Scheduler will see that **Task 2** is in ready state and will execute it.

**My throughts:**

For me it looks like there is a notification behind all of that. If a task has been delayed it will be blocked, but a notification after the delay will set the Task again in ready state.

Meanwhile there is a periodic check from the Scheduler and if he finds a Task that has higher priority than the current executing one it will block it and execute the one with higher priority.

**Then**:

**a)** Will the Scheduler Block **Task 2** after **100 ms** to return back to **Task 1** - Only if Task 1 has higher priority than **Task 2**

**b)** Will the Scheduler continue executing **Task 2** and after that back to **Task 1**, which means that the delay will not be **100 ms** for **Task 1** - Only if Task 1 and Task 2 have same priority.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the kernel is configured as *preemptive* or not.

In preemptive configuration (which is the default one), delays are evaluated on each RTOS tick, and Task 1's state changes from blocked to ready. If it's the highest priority task in the system, the scheduler switches to it.

In cooperative configuration, Task 2 continues to run until it blocks on a semaphore, queue etc. or calls `taskYIELD()` even after Task 1 becomes ready again. I'm not sure if periodic tick interrupt still occurs and updates task states which are blocked on delays.